# Unescape Unicode char in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am expecting to get a string containing non ascii chars, for eg. the string `Øvo`, but the string I get instead contains a different representation of that char: `Ã\u0098vo`. How can I convert this to the string I want?

I know how this string represention is obtained but I can't undo that encoding:

```
let modelString = JSON.stringify(model);
return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(modelString)));
```

I have been trying a lot of functions (from Firefox console) but I'm not getting the expected result:

- window.atob(escape(decodeURIComponent('Ã\u0098vo'))) -> Uncaught DOMException: String contains an invalid character
- escape(decodeURIComponent('Ã\u0098vo')) -> "%C3%98vo"
- JSON.parse('["Ã\u0098vo"]')[0] -> "Ã\u0098vo"
- JSON.parse('["Ã\u0098vo"]')[0] -> "Ã\u0098vo"
- unescape('Ã\u0098vo') -> "Ã\u0098vo"
- unescape('Ã\u0098vo') -> "Ã\u0098vo"
- String.fromCharCode(parseInt('98',64)) -> "\u0000"
- String.fromCharCode(parseInt('98')) -> "b"

Comment: Wouldn't you want `decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(modelString)))` to do the exact reverse of what was done?

Comment: That gives an error because "string contains invalid character". I think the input for atob should be a Base64 encoded string and 'Ã\u0098vo' doesn't meet this assumption https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_atob.asp. Or I'm missing something

Comment: Yeah, because the output of `btoa` should be base64, right? Then the code you've specified for how you got the string, isn't how you got the string...

Comment: Hm... I just tried `window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent("Øvo")));` in the console and is giving me `'w5h2bw=='`

Comment: First `Øvo` is not an ASCII string, because it contains non ASCII chars and second what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Third `unescape` is assumed as out of standards  so you should use `decodeURI` or `decodeURIComponent`, but that's not the problem and you can have `return`  just inside a function, but not inside a simple inline code ...

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `unescape` as it is "removed from the Web standards"!

```js
var model = {"key": "Øvo"};
var modelString = JSON.stringify(model);
var uriEncoded = encodeURIComponent(modelString);

console.log(uriEncoded);
// wrong
console.log(unescape(uriEncoded));
// right
console.log(decodeURIComponent(uriEncoded));

// btoa convertion
var b2a = btoa(decodeURIComponent(uriEncoded));
console.log(b2a);
// the reverse conversion
var a2b = atob(b2a);
console.log(a2b);
```

Comment: That `window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(model)))` was someone's hack to fix a bug on the server processing this string. So I'm looking into fixing that bug properly and then using a simple `window.btoa(model)`. I hope I won't have to work around this hack